# How Restricted Boltzman Machine (RBM) generates hand-written digit?

Tags: deep-learning, restricted-boltzmann-machine

I am reading RBMs from [this paper](https://christian-igel.github.io/paper/TRBMAI.pdf). In Fig1 they show an example of generating hand-written digit using RBMs. This is the figure they are showing:
[image]

In the learning step first we sample $h$ from $h \sim P(h|v)$ and then reconstructe $v$ from $v \sim P(v|h)$. Now in the generating step they are sampling $v$ from $v \sim P(v|h)$. My question is, in generating step if we do not sample $h$ from $h \sim P(h|v)$ how can we get $P(v|h)$?